# Does the mime-type of the Facebook Graph API cause an error on IE8?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Strangly on IE8 when I log into the documentation of the Graph API of Facebook and click on any of the exemple link it ask me to download a file.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

I tried on differents computer (Windows 7).
It works fine on Firefox and Chrome.

Does it do the same for all of you?

**EDIT:** See my comment to view the error.

Comment: See my error: [file](http://dezobi.net/tmp/facebook-ie8.PNG)

Comment: I get the same error but the thing is that you are supposed to open those links programatically, not in a browser. Yes it is annoying but not a dealbreaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not broken at all - just a MIME-type handling issue.

The Graph API response are **text/javascript**, which apparently IE8 doesn't like to render directly in the browser window, but rather presents to the user for downloading.

Nothing's broken.  And like serg555 said, the data in the Graph is really meant to be consumed by machines, not humans via a browser.

Comment: It's just strange that it was working before and now Facebook have change the mime-type.
The guys at Facebook are all using Firefox?  Nobody tought usefull to explain that their exemples don't work on IE8.

Comment: IE has security issues if you use another mime type which would enable the browser to render it inline. The mime type is also (somewhat) accurate, so it's the "right thing".