# Graph API not working in older IEs

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api

I can't seem to get the Facebook Graph API to work in IE7, IE8, and Opera while it is working fine in FF3.6, FF8, IE9, and Chrome.

I am following the Client-side Flow from the [Facebook authentication docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

I have a Facebook Connect link and when the user clicks on it the page is directed to:

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&response_type=token

The user logs in and authorizes the app if needed.

The `redirect_uri` page gets the access_token back just fine.  I then try to do an ajax get for `https://graph.facebook.com/me` to just return the public data (I need name and id).

The request does not succeed.

Doing some research and finding this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424376/does-the-mime-type-of-the-facebook-graph-api-cause-an-error-on-ie8) I tried changing the ajax response type to 'text/javascript' (also tried several others).  Same issues occurs.

Removing ajax from the equation I try to hit the API directly with the browser (not logged into Facebook and without an access_token) like this example from [Facebook Graph API Reference page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

> https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor

I can view it fine in FF. I can download and then view it fine with IE9. I get this error in IE8:

> Unable to download btaylor/ from graph.facebook.com.
>
> Unable to open this Internet site.  The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later.

While searching for answers I found this [stackoverflow post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8159763/graph-api-explorer-not-working-in-ie8), and sure enough Facebook's [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) does not work in IE8.

I can't find much else on this topic which seems to say I am doing something horribly wrong.  Or have developers given up on IE < 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight up GET request doesn't work in IE 8 because IE 8 can't understand the JSON format that the data is coming back in and so it crashes. For the AJAX response, you should set the AJAX reponse to `application/json`, not `text/javascript`. Is there a reason you can't just use the Facebook JS SDK? For example:

```
FB.init({ // options });

FB.api('/me', function(response)
{
    // do stuff
});
```

I'm not actually sure why the Graph API explorer isn't working in IE 8, but for me, the explorer throws Javascript errors but doesn't crash the browser, while loading a Graph response via a GET results in a browser crash.

Comment: Thank you Jimmy for responding.  I tried to use application/json for the ajax response but get the same error.  We are trying to move away from the JS SDK because we where having some problems with permissions and we where under the impression that it was being deprecated. Looks like that is not entirely true [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591960/when-is-facebook-deprecating-the-javascript-sdk). Looks like i should take a look at and try to fix our problems with SDK since the Open Graph API isn't working with IE7 and IE8. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is most likely just a typo on your part for the question, but the correct Facebook authorization URL is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&response_type=token
```

Other than that, I really can't see anything else that you are doing wrong. Looks like IE8 is on its way out.

Comment: Thanks for finding that typo Jordan.